# Testing Parameters of XML tag before extracting data in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

I am trying to look at the  tag of a  in XML. I have my script running down to the dbReferences (there are several for an entry), but I only want to take the 'id' if the 'type' = "EC".

I am thinking of doing some type of if statement, where it will look at the 'type' of the dbReference before taking the id:

```
foreach $entry (@{$data->{entry}}) {         
        foreach $ref (@{$entry->{dbReference}}) {
            if($ref type ="EC"){
                #then print the id
            }
        }
 }
```

Edit:
The entry XML would be formatted like this, with a lot of dbReferences in a row, that need to be checked:

```
<dbReference type="NCBI Taxonomy" id="9606"/>
<dbReference type="PubMed" id="8274401"/>
<dbReference type="EC" id="1.1.5.54"/>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: yu should write `if ($ref eq "EC")`

Comment: dbReference has a bunch of parameters, id, length, type, property, etc. How can I specify that I am testing type in the if statement?

Comment: Can you please post an sample input and what you expacted?

Comment: I updated the main post with an edit of what the xml looks like. the code is already parsed with XML::Simple. I'm not sure how to access the type and id parameters of a the dbReference, as they're not in the body of a tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could use XPath for that. This expression returns the `id` for all `dbReference` elements (in any nesting level) that have a `type` attribute equal to `EC`:

```
//dbReference[@type="EC"]/@id
```

Code snippet:

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file('file.xml');
my $node = $dom->findnodes('//dbReference[@type="EC"]/@id');
print 'Result: '.$node;
```

You could adjust the expression with extra restrictions (ex: an absolute path to the node, or other attributes, node position, etc.) in case this doesn't return a unique value.

Comment: can i incorporate the findnodes method to the for loop? That way I could keep the values for each entry together.

Comment: Yes, but if you choose this solution you might want to use XPath for that as well, since it would be more efficient. You can return a set of nodes and loop on them. See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039143/how-can-i-access-attributes-and-elements-from-xmllibxml-in-perl?rq=1), for an example.

Comment: can you explain how I would alter the registersNs line for my example, I don't see the point of that line.

Comment: That's because his example uses a namespace so his element selectors need to be prefixed (`ns:tagname`) and the prefix needs to be mapped to a namespace. If your XML file does not declare a `xmlns` you don't need that.

Comment: so the code you posted above should be storing the id of all dbReference tags that have the type ="EC". Correct? I added print $dom to the end of the code and it returns all my xml code

Comment: Sorry. I didn't test it and forgot to assign the variable. I'll fix it. It's simpler now. It should print the ID.

Comment: is there some way to store the id numbers in an array or something. I need to manipulate the ids further, so they need to be separate strings

Answer (score 0):

I guess yor input is somthing like

```
<xml>
<dbReference type="NCBI Taxonomy" id="9606"/>
<dbReference type="PubMed" id="8274401"/>
<dbReference type="EC" id="1.1.5.54"/>
<dbReference type="NCBI Taxonomy" id="9606"/>
<dbReference type="PubMed" id="8274401"/>
<dbReference type="EC" id="1.1.5.54"/>
```

so try:

```
my $ref = XMLin($String);


                #warn Dumper($ref);
       foreach $ref1 (keys %{$ref->{dbReference}}) {
            if($ref->{dbReference}->{$ref1}->{type} eq "EC"){
                #then print the id
                $ref1;
            }
        }
```